# Verbs as CakePHP controllers

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp, coding-style

Typically you are supposed to use a plural form of the Model you are using for a controller (eg: `UsersController` is for the `User` model, which corresponds with the `users` table).  However, I want to add a controller that isn't really associated with any model or table, like a "Getting Started" set of pages.

I just wonder what the preferred way of handling something like this is for CakePHP.

Comment: routes are the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always do that.
just make sure you set the $uses array correctly

var $uses = array();

if you dont need any model or

var $uses = array('MyModel');

if you want to use a particular model in this controller

Answer (score 4):

If those are static pages, put them in `views/pages/` and access them via `/pages/xyz`. This uses the standard PagesController. If you want to make shorter routes instead of `/pages/...`, create new routes in `config/routes.php` (the default `/` route shows an example).

If they are dynamic pages and need a real controller, name it whatever you want.